# How to update page description with API?

Tags: development, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-pages, content, pages

I am using the rest API for updating the content of a page on a Modern Site. I am POSTing this

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.SitePagesItem"
    },
    "Title": "this is the new title",
    "Description": "and this is the description",
    "CanvasContent1": "updated content here"
}
```

to URL

```
https://asdasd.sharepoint.com/sites/devtest/_api/web/lists/getbyid('b218bf08-d5af-4da0-9587-60682c6d3f1c')/items(10)
```

The Title and the Content are updated, but the Description remains the same.
How can I update the Description?

Comment: I tried from side, I faced the same issue. the Description column refuse to be updated via an HTTP request !!